# read a file in NiFi with expression

Tags: python, groovy, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow triggered by e-mail.
The problem is that ListFile and GetFile processors are not initiated externally.

**What I need:**

I have some files:

```
context variable #{folder_to_read} = /home/input
#{folder_to_read}/MyBranches_2023-10-22_225510.csv
#{folder_to_read}/MyAccounts_2023-10-22_225510.csv
#{folder_to_read}/MyOrders/USAOrders_2023-10-22_215510.csv
#{folder_to_read}/MyOrders/EUAOrders_2023-10-22_215610.csv
...
```

I need to:

- receive a letter and initiate flowfile (done by ConsumeEWS processor)
- check and read a file by the patterns like `MyBranches_$(now():format('yyyy-MM_dd'))_*.csv` in the input folder
- manipulate with data in a file (files).

The problem is that I can't find how to do it in one pipeline. ListFile and GetFile processors cannot be triggerd by e-mail, fenchfile doesn't accept a regular-like pattern.

Could you share how to do it in NiFi?
Maybe it is possible to do this by ExecuteScript processor + python/groovy?

Comment: It's not clear how from ConsumeEWS you are getting file list. Are files coming through email?

Comment: it's definitely possible to do it with executescript. i can help with groovy - but i need to understand what's the input and expected output.

Comment: Daggett, all files are saved in a shared folder. email just initiate flowfiles

Comment: is groovy acceptable for the answer?

Comment: Yes, why not) I'm not good in Java, but if you can help with groovy, it will be perfect

Comment: i appreciate if you add groovy as an option in question and as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following answer provides groovy as soon as question owner accepts this language as well

---

I assume that incoming flowfile looks like this:

```python
#some comment
filename1.ext
filename2.ext2
subfolder/filename3.ext3
```

use `GroovyExecuteScript` processor, add `base_path` parameter to it that points to a folder with files you want to read and set script body to:

```js
def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return

//read lines from incoming file and filter comments and empty lines
def lines = ff.read().withReader("UTF-8"){r-> r.readLines()}.findAll{s-> s && !s.startsWith('#')}

def outFiles = []
lines.each{s->
    def ffOut = ff.clone(false) //clone all attributes, but not content
    ffOut.filename = s
    new File("${base_path}/${s}").withInputStream{rawIn->
        ffOut.write{rawOut-> rawOut << rawIn} // import content from file
    }
    outFiles.add(ffOut)
}

ff.remove() //drop current flowfile
REL_SUCCESS << outFiles //transfer to success new file list
```